# How to create a sequential number based on date from a parallel transaction?

Tags: mysql, typescript, transactions, duplicates

**OVERVIEW**

I have this e-commerce app that buy some goods and such. I create the app using typescript and ORM Sequelize. So I have this example table that will insert generated invoice number sequential based on current days.

```
CREATE TABLE `dm_generate_trx` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `increment_value` int NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `flag_hit` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

The table would look like this.

```
|id |date      |increment_value|flag_hit|created_at         |updated_at         |
|---|----------|---------------|--------|-------------------|-------------------|
|118|2022-05-19|1              |N       |2022-05-19 10:10:21|2022-05-19 10:10:21|
|126|2022-05-19|2              |N       |2022-05-19 10:10:54|2022-05-19 10:10:54|
|134|2022-05-19|3              |N       |2022-05-19 10:11:37|2022-05-19 10:11:37|
|142|2022-05-20|1              |N       |2022-05-20 08:12:14|2022-05-20 08:12:14|
|150|2022-05-20|2              |N       |2022-05-20 08:12:34|2022-05-20 08:12:34|
```

so in my typescript code I have this query before created the invoice number. So each day if the date is changed, the incremental is start to one again (just like the table up there).

```
const count = await dm_generate_trx.count({
        where: {
          createdAt: {
            [Op.gt]: todayStart, // the value will be "DATE NOW 00:00:00"
            [Op.lt]: now,
          },
        },
        transaction,
      });
      const currentCount = count + 1;
```

Or in SQL it would be like this

```
SELECT count(*) FROM dm_generate_trx 
WHERE createdAt > 'DATE NOW 00:00:00' AND createdAt < 'DATE NOW HH:MM:SS'
```

And then I would sum with 1 and the result like this line

```
const currentCount = count + 1;
```

And then I would insert it into database.

**PROBLEM**

I got a problem when there are two or more transaction that run at the same time, the script also run and commit at the mostly-exact same time, maybe just milliseconds different. The incremental will duplicate because the transaction when run the count query script, didn't catch the first inserted value.

What I would expect the result will be

| id | date | increment_value | flag_hit | created_at | updated_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 118 | 2022-05-19 | 1 | N | 2022-05-19 10:10:21 | 2022-05-19 10:10:21 |
| 126 | 2022-05-19 | 2 | N | 2022-05-19 10:10:54 | 2022-05-19 10:10:54 |
| 134 | 2022-05-19 | 3 | N | 2022-05-19 10:11:37 | 2022-05-19 10:11:37 |
| 135 | 2022-05-19 | 4 | N | 2022-05-19 10:12:37 | 2022-05-19 10:12:37 |
| 142 | 2022-05-20 | 1 | N | 2022-05-20 08:12:14 | 2022-05-20 08:12:14 |
| 150 | 2022-05-20 | 2 | N | 2022-05-20 08:12:34 | 2022-05-20 08:12:34 |

But instead, I got the duplicate data like this.

| id | date | increment_value | flag_hit | created_at | updated_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 118 | 2022-05-19 | 1 | N | 2022-05-19 10:10:21 | 2022-05-19 10:10:21 |
| 126 | 2022-05-19 | 1 | N | 2022-05-19 10:10:54 | 2022-05-19 10:10:54 |
| 134 | 2022-05-19 | 1 | N | 2022-05-19 10:11:37 | 2022-05-19 10:11:37 |
| 135 | 2022-05-19 | 2 | N | 2022-05-19 10:12:37 | 2022-05-19 10:12:37 |
| 142 | 2022-05-20 | 1 | N | 2022-05-20 08:12:14 | 2022-05-20 08:12:14 |
| 150 | 2022-05-20 | 1 | N | 2022-05-20 08:12:34 | 2022-05-20 08:12:34 |

How to solve this issue ? I have tried `ISOLATION_LEVELS.READ_UNCOMMITTED` and still didnt work. Do i have to solve this using code script or database ?

Comment: I don't see the definition of `last_count`.  Why have two unique keys?

Comment: You _will_ have missing invoice numbers; how do you plan to handle such?  You cannot use `AUTO_INCREMENT`.  You must build a robust sequence generator.  Perhaps a Stored proc.

Comment: @RickJames, edited, sorry

Comment: @RickJames, yes but how do i make that ? i have no clue for creatting sequence generator or experience in that

Answer (score 2):

What you have is a race condition.

Using `READ_UNCOMMITTED` doesn't solve this*, because you still have a brief moment between reading the current value, incrementing it in Typescript, and then inserting it into the table. That moment might seem so brief that it's impossible for a problem to occur, but trust me — it will.

There's an old saying regarding unlikely events: **"One in a million is next Tuesday."** Even if an event is extremely rare, if you repeat the conditions that could lead to the event many, many times, it'll happen sooner than you think. You should also read about the [Birthday problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem).

You can't solve this without some kind of locking to ensure the concurrent transactions are not in a race condition. One has to wait while the other commits its value.

Typically in MySQL this is solved with the AUTO_INCREMENT feature. Each session can insert to the same table in concurrent transactions. The table keeps track of the most recently allocated auto-increment id. The insert acquires a table lock only long enough to generate the next id, then it releases that table lock.

But the auto-increment feature doesn't support what you want, an incrementing number that restarts from 1 each day. To do that, you have to make each session lock the table, read the current max value, increment it, and finally insert the incremented value. You can do this with the [LOCK TABLES](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/lock-tables.html) statement.

There is no conventional transactional way of solving this, because you would still have a race condition.

---

* In fact, I have never seen a legitimate use for `READ_UNCOMMITTED`.

Comment: So its database-level to solve this, not the code-level ?

Comment: Right. You can't solve this with code.

Comment: i want to try this but i need some example because i heard about lock table can cause a deadlock like this: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-deadlocks.html

Comment: There are examples on the page I linked to.

Answer (score 1):

So, I think you have two options:

1. Compute the new increment_value then do the insert within a single client transaction.
2. Create a stored procedure, and do this within a single transaction in the database.

The `READ_UNCOMMITTED` isolation level feels wrong. You wouldn't want dirty reads when figuring out count data. You want the isolation level to tell you what has already been committed.

Comment: how could i do that? i need some example or maybe some read to do this

Comment: https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/other-topics/transactions/

Answer (score 1):

Plan A:

Build a database table for keeping the sequence number in.  Use transactions to avoid race conditions.  The table might have 2 columns: the year and the last used sequence number.

If you cannot allow missing invoice numbers (for accounting reasons), I suggest you provide a way to assign a "VOIDed" invoice to any number that is lost.

Plan B:

Avoid the year + sequence number for invoice numbers.

(Sorry, I have no Accounting background, so I do not know all the necessary details.)

Answer (score 1):

Specifically for MY SQL you can use secondary auto increment
In your case **date** and **increment** value

[Using AUTO_INCREMENT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/example-auto-increment.html)

and if **id** column is required too you may write a trigger for that

Queries should be something like

```
CREATE TABLE `dm_generate_trx` (
  `id` int,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `increment_value` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `flag_hit` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`date`, `increment_value`)
)

CREATE TRIGGER dm_generate_trx_id
BEFORE INSERT ON dm_generate_trx
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
      DECLARE nid INT;
      SELECT  COALESCE(MAX(id), 0) + 1
      INTO    nid
      FROM    dm_generate_trx

      
      SET NEW.id = nid;
END;
```

Hopes that helps

Comment: how could the trigger reset the count if the date is change ?

Comment: i need to reset the auto increment to 1 again, for the new date.

Comment: In above code My SQL will be managing it as a secondary index and will reset to 0 with new day, and id is incremented through procedure, do you want vice versa?

Comment: `WHERE   account = NEW.account;`, i don't see any column with account ?

Comment: That was typo, updated where condition